# Label.Autoellipsis text moves up

Tags: vb.net

I'm encountering an issue when using a Label. It has Autosize property set to False, AutoEllipsis property set to True and TextAlign set to MiddleLeft. The Label has also a fixed size of (296, 25).

The problem:

As soon as the text reaches boundary limits it displays "..." but also moves text to the upper corner. I'm assuming this is because label size is greater than the text font, therefore it tries to fit more text within the control. I don't want this behavior. I want text to be single line only and when ellipsis is displayed I want it to remain text position set in properties.

Any ideas how to fix this bug?

Comment: Try setting the label's `UseCompatibleTextRendering` to `true`

Comment: @Icemanind I tried that and it seem to work. However, the text is still moved up by 1px.... very strange

Answer (score 0):

You can measure your `Label`'s text `Width` first and then give some top `Padding` if `Label`'s `Width` is smaller. In other words, when `Label`'s `AutoEllipsis` "happens".

```
Dim _TextSize As System.Drawing.Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(YourLabel.Text, YourLabel.Font)
If _TextSize.Width > YourLabel.Width Then
    YourLabel.Padding = New Padding(0, 6, 0, 0)
Else
    YourLabel.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
End If
```